# Ruby how to format nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have two queries I am running and iterating over both and my final hash is seen below. But, I want to have format on how the data is being stored in the hash that I'm creating or format it after I'm done creating it. But I am not sure how to achieve the desired format where the `names` fall under the same `id` as show below

desired format of example data:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        accepted: false,
        trans: 10234
        names: [
            { name: "Joe", amount: "$1,698.00" },
            { name: "Smith", amount: "$674.24" },
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        accepted: true,
        trans: 10234,
        names: [
            { name: "Joe", amount: "$1,698.00" },
            { name: "Smith", amount: "$674.24" },
        ]
    }
]
```

current format I have

```
[
    {
               :id => 1,
               :accepted => false,
               :trans => 8,
               :name => "Smith",
               :amount => 36.0
    },
    {
               :id => 1,
               :amount => false,
               :trans => 8,
               :name => "Joe",
               :amount => 6.0
    },
    {
               :id => 3,
               :accepted => false,
               :trans => 8,
               :name => "Tom",
               :amount => 34.0
    },
     {
               :id => 3,
               :accepted => false,
               :trans=> 8,
               :name => "Martha",
               :amount => 4.0
    }
], 
[
    {
               :id => 2,
               :accepted => true,
               :trans => 7,
               :name => "Bob",
               :amount => 35.0
    },
     {
                :id => 2,
                :accepted => true,
                :trans => 7,
                :name => "John",
                :amount => 5.0
    }
]
```

logic for creating hash

```
imports = ListImports.limit(20).order(created_at: :DESC)
groups = imports.map{|import| ListImportGroup.where(list_import_id: import.id)}
pub_hash_true = []
pub_hash_false = []
hash = []
imports.map do |import|
  hash << {
     id: import.id,
     trans: import.trans,
     accepted: import.amount
  }
end
  hash.each do |import|
    groups.flatten.each do |group|
      accepted = import[:accepted]
      num_transactions = import[:trans]
      if accepted == false
        pub_hash_false << {id: import[:id], accepted: accepted, trans: num_transactions, name: group.name, amount: group.amount}
      else
        pub_hash_true << {id: import[:id], accepted: accepted, trans: num_transactions, name: group.name, amount: group.amount}
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: How are you generating the final result? It may make more sense to change the generation than reformatting after the fact

Comment: @SaraFuerst I'm iterating over two sets of data and creating the hash that way. I updated my question to include the logic

Comment: What is `groups`? You didn't show where the variable comes from.

Comment: And why do you need `pub_hash_true` and `pub_hash_false`? Your question wasn't originally about splitting the data into "true/false" groups, and you haven't shown if/how those variables are being used.

Comment: @TomLord it returns as one hash when being called by the controller. I updated my question though to show where groups comes from. It is the resulting query. ```pub_hash_true``` and ``` pub_hash_false``` is to separate the accepted: true/false values

Comment: I understand that `pub_hash_true` and `pub_hash_false` are splitting the result into to sets. My point was that this doesn't appear to be used for anything, so I'm unclear if you need this additional logic as part of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Note: You didn't specify what is the association between `ListImport` and `ListImportGroup`.
# However, I'm fairly sure you could be fetching this data via a JOIN query like below,
# rather than making up to 20 additional database calls to fetch the associated records.

imports = ListImports.limit(20).order(created_at: :DESC).includes(:list_import_group)

result = imports.map do |import|
  {
    id: import.id,
    trans: import.trans,
    accepted: import.amount,
    names: import.list_import_groups.pluck(:name, :amount)
  }
end
```

And if you do actually need to filter for imports where `accepted` is `true` or `false`, you could do something like this instead of building separate arrays manually:

```
accepted_imports = result.select { |import| import[:accepted] }
# and
rejected_imports = result.reject { |import| import[:accepted] }

# or even:
accepted_imports, rejected_imports = result.partition { |import| import[:accepted] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the exact correspondence between the *desired* and *current* formats.
But I assume

- For the entries with the same `id`, the values of `accepted` and `trans` are identical.
- the desired amount for Joe in the *current format* is identical in the corresponding amount in the *desired amount*. (In your example, the former is `6.0` whereas the latter is `"$1,698.00"`, which does not make sense.)

Then, the following would do the conversion. The array `ahout` is in the desired format.

```rb
 # Let us assume "a1" is the original array in the "current format"
hout = {}
a1.flatten.map{|h|
   h.slice(*(%i(id trans name amount accepted))).values
}.each{ |a|
  hout[a[0]] = {id: a[0], accepted: a[4], trans: a[1], names: []} if !hout.key? a[0]
  hout[a[0]][:names].push(
    {name: a[2], amount: "$"+helper.number_with_precision(a[3], precision: 2, delimiter: ',')}
  )
}

ahout = hout.values
```

You may want to sort `ahout`, if you like.

Note that I am assuming you are using Rails 5+. Otherwise, the method `helper` may not work. In that case, you can use `sprintf` or whatever formatting method.